# pd.read_excel Read only excel formulas not values

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I'm trying to read only the formulas in a excel file with Pandas, I was trying this:

```python
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel(file, engine="openpyxl", engine_kwargs={"data_only":False})
```

but I get this error:

> **TypeError**: openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook() got multiple values
> for keyword argument 'data_only'

I would like to know how to do it, and why the error

Comment: My guess: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f00efd0344bd4e22cc867e76c776cb88669e6cde/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py#L573

Comment: Why use pandas instead of openpyxl directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's an issue you might need to check or open on [*GitHub*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues).

As a workaround (in [`2.1.0`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases/tag/v2.1.0)), you can comment the [*line 573*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/ba1cccd19da778f0c3a7d6a885685da16a072870/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py#L573) in the file `io\excel\_openpyxl.py`.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel("file.xslx", engine="openpyxl", engine_kwargs={"data_only": False})
```

Or you can simply use [openpyxl](/questions/tagged/openpyxl) :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("file.xlsx", data_only=False)

vals = wb["Sheet1"].values;cols = next(vals)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=cols)
```

If you want to mask the plain data, you can use :

```
funcs_only = [
    [cell.value if cell.data_type == "f" else ""
     for cell in row] for row in wb["Sheet1"]
]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(funcs_only[1:], columns=next(wb["Sheet1"].values))
```

Outputs :

```
print(df1)

         col1      col2
0         foo  =TODAY()
1         bar         A
2  =A2&"/"&A3         B


print(df2)

         col1      col2
0              =TODAY()
1                      
2  =A2&"/"&A3
```

Used input (*file.xlsx*) :

[image]